# Running adb as root from an Ubuntu machine

Tags: android, adb, mount

I'm trying to modify the hosts file on my android phone and I am using adb for this on Ubuntu 20.04 to pull the file, modify it and push it back as suggested [here](https://www.modmy.com/how-modify-hosts-file-your-android-device). I was able to pull the file but when I try to push it I get an error

```
adb: error: failed to copy 'Documents/hosts' to '/system/etc/hosts': remote couldn't create file: Read-only file system
```

One suggestion seems to be to run `adb remount` or `adb shell mount -o rw,remount /system` (I'm not sure if these meant to be run on the android device itself) and this doesn't work for me, I get

```
/system/bin/sh: /system/bin/remount: inaccessible or not found
```

To this, there seems to be a suggestion to run `adb root` which returns `adbd cannot run as root in production builds`. Now I'm not sure how to proceed. There are some threads online saying what to do about this but I feel this is way above my head already. I just want to push the hosts file back to the phone. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Modifying the hosts file on Android requires a rooted device. If your phone is not rooted it will not work no matter what you do.

Comment: my device is rooted

Comment: by this i mean that I have a custom ROM on it (Calyx). Do I need to do something else/enable something before I can modify the hosts file?

Comment: If your device is rooted why don't you make use of it? Just execute `adb shell` then `su` to become root and finally `mount -o rw,remount /system`.